# vhost rewrite rules in apache - get rid of the subdomain without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts

I know similar questions have been asked, but for the life of me I can't seem to make it work.

The idea is to rewrite the subdomain as part of the url. We also want the request to be handled by the server without making remote calls, and the url in the client to not be re-written.

To put it simply:
`http://test.example.com/(something)` should be interpreted as `http://example.com/test/(something)`

'something' is optional.

I've tried a done of different solutions, but never seem to get it quite right - this is my first experience with that.

```
#   RewriteEngine on 
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com [NC]
#   RewriteRule ^((?!test/).*)$ /test/$1 [L,NC]

#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [NC] 
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  "test%{REQUEST_URI}" 
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]  

#RewriteEngine on 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/test/%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L,NC]
```

It is important to know that `example.com/test/something` already exists on a different server and should NOT be used or called.

My thinking was to redirect `test.example.com` to the new server and then interpret it on the new server as `example.com/test` by using another vhost (the whole application is being developped without subdomains, but we are going to migrate part by part using subdomains, until we manage to migrate everything and restore the 'normal' way).

In time, we will have sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, etc. Aliases might play a role here, but I'm out of my depth.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have access to the server config / vHost for the subdomain? Does the server that is accepting the initial request (to `test.example.com`) host other domains? (Just wondering why you are explicitly checking the requested hostname when the target is on a different server?)

Comment: @MrWhite I think the best answer is that I don't know what I am doing, and that's why I'm explicitly checking the hostname - it's all experiment at the moment. In the end, the server will only host sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com (to be rewritten), admin.example.com (not rewritten) and _in the future_ example.com. Example.com is somewhere else at the moment. I do have access to all I want for now - I just can't expose example.com without subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you require a "reverse proxy" since `example.com` is physically hosted on a different server. (However, you state in comments that "in the future" `example.com` would be back on the same server - at that time you may not need the "reverse proxy" if the subdomain and main domain point to the same filesystem - a simple rewrite may suffice.)

To configure a reverse proxy you need to ensure that mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http (for HTTPS) are enabled and possibly some other (optional) proxy modules depending on requirements.

For what you require, where you are passing the same URL-path from source to target, you can use the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives in the virtualhost container for the `test.example.com` subdomain:

```
ProxyPass / http://example.com/test/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/test/
```

Alternatively, if you needed a more complex mapping, or if you want/need to do this in `.htaccess` then you can use mod_rewrite with the `P` flag (as you are doing above):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/test%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Importantly, you need the absolute URL (scheme + hostname) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (missing from your example).

If this host only accepts requests to `test.example.com` then the preceding condition is not required.

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server contains the slash prefix, so this should be omitted in the *substitution* string. And since you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable and not a backreference then you don't need the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `^(.*)$` can be simplified to just `^`. The `L` is not required when used with `P`, since `L` is implied.

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive answer. I'll give that a try as soon as possible, but it looks like the proxy was my main missing brick. Thanks again!